# How to use pluggables functions on plugins

Tags: wordpress

I need to use functions such as `wp_insert_user` and `wp_update_user` in a plugin, but theses functions call others functions who are not yet loaded (such as `get_user_by` or `get_userdata`).

If I require the `pluggable.php` file where I use theses functions it works, but messing with WordPress load orders seems a pretty bad idea to me.

How would you use theses functions in a plugin ?

Comment: Chances are your plugin is being run too soon. Without seeing your code though we can only guess.

Comment: @cabrerahector I was calling theses function on the plugin load, and all plugins are loaded before `wp-includes/pluggable.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at how ACF plugin do it, I've found a solution, instead of calling the function at the plugin load, I just add it to the action `init`.

```php
require 'myClass.php';
$myClass = new myClass();

add_action('init', [$myClass, 'myFunction']);
```

I would even suggest to use a main class for your plugins and in the `__construct` hook your logic to `init` and/or `plugins_loaded`.

```php
class MyPlugin {
  public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [$this, 'plugins_loaded'] );
    add_action( 'init', [$this, 'init'] );
  }

  public function plugins_loaded() {
    // pluggables functions are available here
  }

  public function init() {
    // pluggables functions are available here
  }
}
new MyPlugin();
```